# Remove data from list after few hours

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I have one type of data collection which is having `eventDateTime` field. For 6 hours data should display in list after 6 hours it should not be listed. Here I am sending you query,

```
  Events.find({$and: [{eventDateTime: {$lt: 21600}}, {isDisabled: false}, {isDeleted: false} ]}, function (error, data) {
               callback((error) ?   {} : data);
              }) ;
```

How can I convert `eventDateTime` in seconds and compare with seconds as it is 6 hours?

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution it will help you.

```
Events.find({$and: [{eventDateTime: {$gte: new Date(Date.now() - 6  60  60 * 1000)}},  {isDisabled: false}, {isDeleted: false} ]}, function (error, data) {
                callback((error) ? {}   : data);
            }) ;
```